# Как сделать мобильное приложения на CSS, HTML, JS?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, мобильные-приложения

Как сделать мобильное приложения на CSS, HTML, JS? Какие есть программы? Но не надо там Kotlin, Flutter, React, а просто этими 3 языками можно как-то сделать?

Comment: Сделать можно. Но в процессе у вас получится кривая версия ReactNative скорее всего. И только на неё уйдёт 95% времени. Если вам надо именно на указанных технологиях делать, то, скорее всего, быстрее выйдет взять уже готовый ReactNative и потратить время на изучение оного.

Comment: Какова задача вашего мобильного приложения? Стек технологий определяется задачей, а не наоборот. Есть еще вариант создать псевдо мобильное приложение с помощью `PWA` технологии. Варианты на самом деле есть, но данных для решения вашего же вопроса очень мало.

Comment: типа как интсаграм фейсбук страницу  с авторизацией и регистр.

Comment: тогда PWA вам должен подойти

Answer (score 0):

Если надо быстро и только на этом стеке технологий, то посмотрите в сторону [jasonette](https://jasonette.com/). Минимальный json файл:

```
{
  "$jason": {
    "head": {
      ...
    },
    "body": {
      "background": {
        "type": "html",
        "url": "file://index.html",
        "action": {
         "type": "$default"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Документация на [сайте](http://docs.jasonette.com/web/)

В чем суть: jasonette - это фреймворк для создания простых мобильных приложений. Вся разметка и логика в json файлах. Есть компонент web container, для отображения html документов.
Web container можно использовать как бэкграунд для экрана приложения. Т.е. качаем jasonette, открываем в android studio, настраиваем файл manifest, настраиваем основной json файл приложения, где в качестве бэкграунда указываем url сайта, или локальный html файл, или код html. Собираем и на выходе получаем нативное приложение.

[Статья на Хабре](https://m.habr.com/ru/company/ruvds/blog/352200/)

Реальный пример: [сайт aimplant.ru](http://aimplant.ru) и [приложение в PlayMarket](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.aimplant)

Answer (score 0):

В принципе, есть решение. Делаете качественную адаптивную верстку, весь функционал. Но, чтобы обернуть это в оболочку приложения, следует все же установить flutter и буквально прописать 20 строк, чтобы сделать WebView. Конечно нужен flutter, но он нужен, только чтобы обернуть сайт в оболочку приложения :)